# How many coordinates are unreachable?

Tags: number-theory, coordinate-systems

I wanted to know, if a man was to go from $(0,0)$ to $(46,46)$ moving only straight and up with the following constraints:-

1. If he walks right, he will walk  atleast $4$ consecutive coordinates.
2. If he moves up, he will walk atleast $12 $ consecutive coordinates.

How many coordinates are unreachable by him in this $46 \times 46$ grid? (Assumption:A coordinate is reachable by the man if he runs through the coordinate.)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that if he goes to $(0,3*12)=(0,36)$ he can no longer go further up as $4*12=48 \gt 46$, or if he goes once further up he goes to $(0,46)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "only straight and up"?

Comment: HE CANNOT GO BEYOND (46,46) 48 IS OUT OF QUESTION.

Comment: That wasn't an option I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reachable points are those that lie on the $1,4,8,12,\dots,40,44$ numbered columns and $1,12,24,36$ numbered rows(numbering being done from bottom to top and from left to right.)

Comment: He cant reach $(46,46)$.

Comment: The real question is this, help me understand it, if the above i have written is wrong. A dog is standing at the bottom left corner of a grid of 46×46 streets. The dog is trying to get to the top right corner of the grid. As the dog runs,it will only ever run up and to the right. Any time the dog runs to the right, it runs at least 4 consecutive blocks right,and any time it runs up,it runs at least 12 consecutive blocks up. How many different intersections are unreachable for the dog by following these rules?

Comment: Details and assumptions
The last stretch that the dog runs must also satisfy the condition on the minimum number of consecutive blocks.

An intersection is reachable if the dog runs through it. It doesn't matter if the dog can change direction at that intersection.

Comment: "help please its urgent" Maybe you shouldn't leave your homework until the last minute.

Comment: You know, you didn't say anything in the original question about running *at least* 4 blocks right; the reasonable interpretation of what you did write was it must run *exactly* 4 blocks right. Please edit the question so it has no hidden assumptions in it. And maybe tell us where the problem comes from.

Comment: so what should be the answer, or any hints

Comment: AND MAYBE TELL US WHERE THE PROBLEM COMES FROM.

Answer (score 1):

All the coordinates but the ones contained within the rectangle with vertices $\,(0,0)\,,\,(4,0)\,,\,(0,12)\,,\,(4,12)\,$ (not including the perimeter) are reachable with the addition of that "at least" thing and understanding that "reachable" means passing through, as you wrote, not **stopping** there...

For example ,$\,(3,9)\,$ is unreachable, but for $\,a\ge 4\;,\;b\ge 12\;,\;\;(a,b)\;$ is reachable: just walk $\,a\;$ steps rightwards and then $\,b\,$ steps upwards...

In fact, we could say any coordinate of the form $\,(a,b)\;,\;\;a\ge 4\;\;or\;\;b\ge 12\;$ , is reachable...

Comment: so acoording to ur answer its 33, but its wrong. Check again please.

Comment: I..."check again"? No dude, **you** check again, and either write the correct wording for the problem, prove I'm wrong...or discover you are right.

Comment: Is the answer 33 using ur method, check and reply,thanks.